# validate model state without passing model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to validate model using below code

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {

  }
```

The issue is that when I passed model object to controller action its working properly but when I called controller action using below code

```
public ActionResult Save()
{
}
```

Then my model state is always return true.So please clarify me is it possible to check ModelState.IsValid using above code.In my case save method is common which is call from multiple controller,so model is not fixed parameter.So please let me know how validate model.

Comment: Is your action method always taking in a model class?  Save above doesn't define that so if you could provide more detail, that would help.

Comment: No.I don't want to pass model class to my save method.I want to validate Model state using below code.public ActionResult Save()
{
  If(ModelState.Isvalid)
  {
  //code goed here after valid 
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

```
ModelState.Clear();
Validate(model);
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC uses a model to extract the validation attributes, as a means for validation.  You can explicitly call `ValidateModel()` or `TryValidateModel()` in the controller directly, but again that is validating a model, using model validation attributes.  If you aren't explicitly using a model, you can access the form directly as you probably know, or can manually validate input and then add appropriate model validation errors using:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "ErrorMessage");
```

Or use this technique depending on how your app is structured: [How to add ModelState.AddModelError message when model item is not binded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936604/how-to-add-modelstate-addmodelerror-message-when-model-item-is-not-binded)